# How to use running status with midiOutShortMsg?

Tags: midi

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-midioutshortmsg), it should be possible to omit the status byte and only send data bytes after I set the status byte by sending the first command.

I'm testing with NoteOn command code (90 hex) and trying to play a chord, but it only works when the status byte is set at each call.

I tried putting the tone number into the lowest byte and velocity into second lowest but no sound was produced...

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds correct, however, if you are not getting the expected result then it's possible your MIDI device is not fully MIDI compliant.

The following *example* code successfully plays a broken chord using running status on the Windows built-in MIDI device on my Windows 11 machine:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Winmm.lib")
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <mmeapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        HMIDIOUT hMidiOut = 0;
        MMRESULT mmResult = midiOutOpen(&hMidiOut, -1, NULL, NULL, CALLBACK_NULL);
        if (mmResult != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            throw std::exception("Failed to open the MIDI device.");
        mmResult = midiOutShortMsg(hMidiOut, 0x007F4090);
        if (mmResult != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            throw std::exception("midiOutShortMsg() failed.");
        Sleep(500);
        mmResult = midiOutShortMsg(hMidiOut, 0x00007F42);
        if (mmResult != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            throw std::exception("midiOutShortMsg() failed.");
        Sleep(500);
        mmResult = midiOutShortMsg(hMidiOut, 0x00007F44);
        if (mmResult != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            throw std::exception("midiOutShortMsg() failed.");
        Sleep(3000);
        midiOutReset(hMidiOut);
        midiOutClose(hMidiOut);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, when I'll have some time and will, I'll try to translate your code into VB and see if it works :) . I'm testing on an ASUS laptop from around 2015 which has a Roland MIDI device built in...

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know how it goes for you.